# Ubuntu One IPCERROR error

Tags: ubuntu-one, 12.10

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10. Now, when I try to enter Ubuntu One, I get: `IPCERROR`.
And another error associated with that:

```
The crashed program seems to use third-party or local libraries:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-11.1.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/_sigchld.so
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-11.1.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/python/_initgroups.so

It is highly recommended to check if the problem persists without those first.

Do you want to continue the report process anyway?
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you've installed a version of Twisted into /usr/local which Python is finding, and which causes problems.

Remove that version of twisted and rely on the system version which is included with Ubuntu, and it should resume working.

Comment: Problem solved. sudo pip uninstall Twisted helped :)